# Options for one-time login browser session

Tags: browser

I always log out from all my accounts on websites when leaving the computer when using other computers than my own, for instance a public computer. This means I have to log in to several accounts every time I switch computer. What are the options to restore all logins with just one log on? Is there any browser that support this? or do I have to run a remote desktop to my home computer?

Comment: Public computers may not give you the ability to use different browsers (even if they had the capability you ask about). You have, however, added an excellent point regarding Remote Desktop. Although not all public computers will allow this, either (ports can be blocked easily), you may be able to use a standalone software that can "Remote Desktop" over HTTPS - I'm unsure whether, say, LogMeIn or TeamViewer have standalone applications... You could then, in theory, have the application and your home IP on a USB stick and run the portable app?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this from a different perspective: Why do you have to log in an account in the first place? Because the site want's to ensure you are the legit owner of the account.

What you are trying to achieve is some kind of sharing your account credentials over several computers. This would e.g. involve copying all your session cookies from different websites to the other computer.

Apart from the fact that depending on the website this would not even work because some sessions are bound to your IP-Adress, this is in general not a very good idea for multiple reasons:

- How can the browser (most likely an Add-On) know, which data/cookies/session/login information it has to copy? It can't - every site uses different mechanisms. Such a tool could only support specific websites, or it cannot be sure it copies all necessary information
- The tool you use must be installed on both computers, so also on a potential public PC and it needs a server side synchronization or direct access to your home computer. In both variants you give your most important data - login/session information - out of your hands
- How should the website handle the fact, that you are using the same session from multiple computers/locations at once? Many sites have mechanisms to prevent exactly that, as this is the common case when hacking/stealing sessions
- How can you be sure that no data is left behind if you don't logout from your accounts (otherwise you couldn't restore you logins)?
- ...

This list could be extended much further.

So I have 2 suggestions for you:

- Use a secure remote desktop or ssh or whatever connection to you home PC to ensure that your session cookies etc. never leave your private computer
- Or, what I would propose: Use a password manager like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/), which dramatically helps in remembering your credentials and makes the login to multiple accounts a negligible effort

Even if there would be a browser supporting such a functionality, I would be very careful in using it. Think about the reasons for having accounts and the importance of logging out in the first place and then think about what you want to achieve with such a single sign-on one once more. I also suggest reading the [Wikipedia article about SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).